Weird behaviour in C when hex value(over 0x7f) is assigned to (signed) char
When a hex value "0x000000a1" is assigned to (signed) char, char is equal to "0xffffffa1".
Can anyone explain this weird behaviour?
void main(){
    char testVar = 0x000000a1;

    printf("%x \n",testVar); //prints ffffffa1
    printf("%d \n",testVar); //prints -95

}

It works as expected when you initialize an unsigned char
void main(){
    unsigned char testVar = 0x000000a1;

    printf("%x \n",testVar); //prints a1
    printf("%d \n",testVar); //prints 161

}

also works as expected when you assign a value within the ASCII limit of 127(or 0x7f)
void main(){
    unsigned char testVar = 0x7f;

    printf("%x \n",testVar); //prints 7f
    printf("%d \n",testVar); //prints 127

}

what I understand now after asking the question:

You can't assign 0x000000a1 to a char, because a char is only 1 byte long. You only assign the a1 part.
The first bit in a signed value indicates if it is negative or not
(1000 0000 is negative and equals to -128. 0111111 is not negative and equals to 127)
For some reason printf needs to extend the char variable to int before it outputs the value.
when printf is converting the signed char to int, it recognises when char is negative and therefore preserving the negative value by extending with 1's instead of 0's.
(1000 0000b(-128dez) is extended to 1111 1111 ... 1111 1111 1000 0000b(still -128dez))


0xA1 has the high-order bit set, so when the (signed) char value is converted to an int as it is passed to printf(), it is sign-extended and prints as a negative number (-95).  This is normal and very much to be expected.  Values 0x00..0x7F are positive but 0x80..0xFF are negative in a (signed) char.

Note that void main() is only valid on Windows (because Microsoft documents it is OK).  Everywhere else, main() returns int.  See What should main() return in C and C++?  Also, printing a space before the newline is not good practice.  Trailing white space should be anathema to you, both in your source code and in your outputs.

char can be signed or unsigned and it's an 8-bit signed type on your platform by default. If it's signed then obviously 0xa1 is outs of range so it can't have the value 161. Most compilers have a switch to toggle between signed and unsigned char

ok i think i get it now correct me if I'm wrong: The first bit of the char variable is a flag for if the value is negative (1000 0000 would be a negative value) now when the char is extended to signed int for the printf statement it extends the char according to if the char is negative or not. I guess when you explicitly tell that char is unsigned, printf doesn't recognise the first bit as a flag for a negative value anymore and therefore it extends the variable with zeros.

no it's a value bit, not a flag, although it's called the sign bit and can be used to check the sign. In modern CPUs negative values are represented as two's complement

char is always one byte long, otherwise your understanding is correct.

Someone asked a similar question recently: char * vs unsigned char *


You can't assign 0x000000a1 to a char, because a char is only 2 bytes long. You only assign the a1 part.

A char is by definition always 1 byte big. (It could have more than 8 bits on exotic systems though.) The key here is rather than char has implementation-defined signedness: it could be either signed or unsigned depending on the compiler. Is char signed or unsigned by default? Apparently it is signed in your case.
The amount of zeroes in front of the value doesn't matter in the slightest and do not affect the type. All they do is to fool the programmer thinking they have some meaning.

The first bit in a signed value indicates if it is negative or not (1000 0000 is negative and equals to -128. 0111111 is not negative and equals to 127)

Yes, if it is the MSB.
What happens when you assing 0xa1 to a signed char is also compiler-specific. On mainstream systems this will result in a negative two's complement value -95 decimal.

or some reason printf needs to extend the char variable to int before it outputs the value.

printf is a variadic function (variable amount of arguments) and for those functions there's a special implicit type promotion rule called "the default argument promotions". When passing a small integer type such as char or short to a variadic function, it will always get implicitly promoted to int. (And when passing float it will get promoted to double.)

when printf is converting the signed char to int, it recognises when char is negative and therefore preserving the negative value by extending with 1's instead of 0's

Correct. During this promotion, if your original type was signed and has a negative value, this is respected and the sign is preserved, so called "sign extension". So in the binary representation of things, rather than having (signed) char 0xa1 = -95, you get int 0xffffffa1 = still -95.
You then lie to printf with %x telling it to expect an unsigned int parameter. Strictly speaking this is undefined behavior, but any sensible compiler will convert the int to unsigned int and that's a well-defined conversion, leaving you with 0xffffffa1 but now it's unsigned representation, so it is equal to decimal value 4294967201.
